# I want to extract a specific value from a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a string from which I want to extract value for test1.
The string is :

```
I_ID [I_ITEM = [I_ITEM [test1 = F135], I_ITEM [test1 = W1972544]]]]]
```

Any pointers will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to capture *all* values whose keys are `test1`, we can try using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "I_ID [I_ITEM = [I_ITEM [test1 = F135], I_ITEM [test1 = W1972544]]]]]"
values = re.findall(r'\btest1\s*=\s*(.*?)\]', inp)
print(values)  # ['F135', 'W1972544']
```